# Add class to document.documentElement with php

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, domdocument

I'm developing a wordpress theme, and I'm setting a cookie based on certain conditions. It works fine — I can set the cookie and retrieve the cookie successfully. My problem is in adding a class to the documentelement based on the value of the cookie, e.g. `<html class="special-class">` if the cookie's value is true and `<html class="regular-class">` if the value is false.

How can I do that in Wordpress? The code I want would be like this:

```
function my_theme_getcookie() {
  if ( isset( $_COOKIE['cookie-name'] ) && $_COOKIE['cookie-name'] == 'true'     ) {
    // Add the class "special-snowflake" to <html> tag...
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_theme_getcookie' );
```

My workaround for now is to add my special class to `<body>` rather than  `<html>` using something based on the following from the Wordpress codex

```
function my_theme_class_names( $classes ) {
    // add 'class-name' to the $classes array
    $classes[] = 'class-name';
    // return the $classes array
    return $classes;
}
```

Then I can call that function when I check for the cookie:

```
function my_theme_getcookie() {
  if ( isset( $_COOKIE['cookie-name'] ) && $_COOKIE['cookie-name'] == 'true'     ) {
    add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_theme_class_names' );
  }
}
```

It looks like there is no html_class() filter analog to body_class()

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this .

```
<?php
    function my_theme_getcookie(){
            if( isset( $_COOKIE['cookie-name'] ) && $_COOKIE['cookie-name'] == 'true' ){?>
               <script>
                    var root = document.getElementsByTagName( 'html' )[0]; // '0' to assign the first (and only `HTML` tag)

                    root.setAttribute( 'class', 'special-snowflake' );
               </script><?php
            }
        } ?>
```

Comment: I'm sure that will work, but it's not the way I was hoping to solve this. I'd rather not use JavaScript in this case — I was hoping to use a wordpress hook such as can be done with add_filter for body class, which lets me add classes to <body>. There doesn't seem to be the equivalent for the <html> tag.

Comment: Search if you could find out . I have never did it with `<html>` tag.